# Alternate Character colors on console c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to alternate some C# characters from blue to white. I have an if statement there to check if the number is odd or even. That does not seem to be working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Ask for minutes.
    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("Minutes?");
    string minutes = Console.ReadLine();
    int mins = int.Parse(minutes);
    for (int i = 0; i < mins; i++)
    {
        // Sixty seconds is one minute.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
        // Write line.
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            //iseven
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine(new string('&', 30));
        }
        else
        {
            //is odd
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 30));
        }

    }
    // Beep ten times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Beep(200,1000);
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("[Done]");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: _"That does not seem to be working"_ what happens instead?

Comment: Check your code again, think a little bit and change it. you did copy and paste?.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements appear to be setting the color to `ConsoleColor.Blue`. Change one of these to `ConsoleColor.White`:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
     //iseven
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
     Console.WriteLine(new string('&', 30));
}
else
{
    //is odd
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; //<--- here.
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 30));
}
```

Comment: I tried that already it did not work.? Did you try compiling and running this?
    Minutes?
1
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Comment: The else statement never runs

Comment: It looks like we go through all of the numbers in the loop. before the else ever runs

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed your main function and it seems that your problem is that you are always setting the Foreground Color to Blue. This will work:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    //iseven
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.WriteLine(new string('&', 30));
                }
                else
                {
                    //is odd
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 30));
                }
```

As simple as changing the first statement in the else clause will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
Console.WriteLine("Minutes?");
string minutes = Console.ReadLine();
int mins = int.Parse(minutes);
for (int i = 0; i < mins; i++)
{
    // Sixty seconds is one minute.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
    // Write line.
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        //iseven
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine(new string('&', 30));
    }
    else
    {
        //is odd
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 30));
    }

}
// Beep ten times.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Beep(200, 1000);
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("[Done]");
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dave Zych's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630665/dave-zych) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32401838/5240004) is correct, I thought I'd just show another way to do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Removed sleep and other calls.
    Console.ForegroundColor = i % 2 == 0 ? ConsoleColor.Blue : ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine(new string(i % 2 == 0 ? '&': '*', 30));
}
```

Free Bonus Method:

```
ConsoleColor[] colors = new ConsoleColor[] { ConsoleColor.Blue, ConsoleColor.White };
char[] messageChars = new char[] { '&', '*' };

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = colors[i % 2];
    Console.WriteLine(new String(messageChars[i % 2], 30));
}
```

Or, if you wanted to be really crazy:

```
Func<int, ConsoleColor> color = i => i % 2 == 0 ? ConsoleColor.Blue : ConsoleColor.White;
Func<int, string> message = i => new String(i % 2 == 0 ? '&' : '*', 30);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color(i);
    Console.WriteLine(message(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dave and theB are also right at their point. But you are looking for this answer where you are trying with input minutes = 1 and result you want foreground color as WHITE as you mentioned into above comment:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Ask for minutes.
  //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  Console.WriteLine("Minutes?");
  string minutes = Console.ReadLine();
  int mins = int.Parse(minutes);
  //for (int i = 0; i < mins; i++)
  for (int i = 1; i <= mins; i++)
  {
     // Sixty seconds is one minute.
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
     // Write line.
     if (i % 2 == 0)
     {
        //iseven
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine(new string('&', 30));
     }
     else
     {
        //is odd
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 30));
     }

  }
  // Beep ten times.
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     Console.Beep(200, 1000);
  }
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  Console.WriteLine("[Done]");
  Console.Read();
}
```

So you need to update your first "for" statment with this:
for (int i = 1; i <= mins; i++)

and ELSE statement for odd with this:
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

That's it. You need to update your code. Your code will work as per expected result.